# Javascript Object Sorting and Adding new property in Modular Approach

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I have following javascript object

```
mData=[{A: "148.0", Bit: 27 ,Ic: "0.4",ked: "229.0",Ted: "228.9985"},
{A: "148.0", Bit: 27 ,Ic: "0.4",ked: "229.0",Ted: "2285"},
{A: "148.0", Bit: 17 ,Ic: "0.4",ked: "259.0",Ted: "28"},
{A: "148.0", Bit: 27 ,Ic: "0.4",ked: "279.0",Ted: "28"},             
{A: "148.0", Bit: 27 ,Ic: "0.4",ked: "239.0",Ted: "82"},
{A: "148.0", Bit: 17 ,Ic: "0.4",ked: "219.0",Ted: "22"},
{A: "148.0", Bit: 16 ,Ic: "0.4",ked: "239.0",Ted: "22"},      
{A: "148.0", Bit: 17 ,Ic: "0.4",ked: "259.0",Ted: "22"}];
```

I am trying to seperate them based on their Bit property. I have came up with very simple algorithm as follows, however it is neither modular or generic. How could I make the following code more generic.

```
color=["red","blue","green"];

data1=[];data2=[];data3=[];

$.each(mData, function (i, wData){
  if(wData.Bit===27)
  {
    wData.color=color[0];
    data1.push(wData);
  }
  else if(wData.Bit===17)
  {
    wData.color=color[1];
    data2.push(wData);
  }
   else
  {
    wData.color=color[2];
    data3.push(wData);
  }
});
```

In addition to that, I would like to add a color property for each object before I push corresponding data, lets say `if BIT>27 color='red', if BIT<27&BIT>17 color='blue', if BIT<17 color='yellow'.`

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vbLz9zc9/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using reduce like this

```
var create_map = function(mData, colors, indexes) {
    return mData.reduce( function(res, curr) {
       var i = indexes[curr.Bit] || 0;
       curr.color = colors[i];
       ( res[i] = res[i] || [] ).push(curr); 
       return res;
    },[]);
}
// define colors and bits which to place into index
var colors = ["red","blue","green"],
    indexes = { 17 : 1, 27 : 2}; // zero default, 17 => index 1
var res = create_map( mData, colors, indexes );  
// res[0] = array of all
// res[1] = array of Bits == 17
// res[2] = array of Bits == 27
```

The demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/1b51eqoq/

Answer (score 1):

Interesting questions! These are actually two questions, so let me answer them one at a time.

#### How to group objects by a certain field?

The kind of operation you try to implement is an group by operation. Let's start by eliminating the hardcoded checks for bit values. To do so, we first want to change our output to a single object instead of multiple arrays. These objects can then have as key the bitvalue, and as value an array containing all objects with that bitvalue. E.g.:

```
result = {
    17 : [ /* All objects with Bit=17 */],
    27 :  [ /* All objects with bit 27 */],
    //etc
};
```

So let's try that:

```
function orderByBit(data) {
    //let's start with an empty object.
    var result = {};
    //array.forEach is similar to $.each(array), but then built-in all
    //non-ancient browsers (that is, >= IE9)
    data.forEach(function(item) {
        var bit = item.Bit;
        //First we check if we already have a array created for the bit value.
        //if not, then we create one
        if (!result[bit]) {
            result[bit] = [];
        }
        //Now we just have to push the item to the correct array
        result[bit].push(item)
    });
    //Done!
    return result;
}

var orderedData = orderByBit(mData);
```

But we can do even better. We now still have hardcoded that we want to group by the value of `Bit`, but we might want to change that as well. To do so we can ask for the field to group as parameter.

```
function orderBy(field, data) {
    //let's start again with an empty object.
    var result = {};
    data.forEach(function(item) {
        //We no longer hardcode the Bit field, instead we use the field
        //passed in as argument
        var fieldValue = item[field];
        //The rest is the same, but now with fieldValue instead of bit
        if (!result[fieldValue]) {
            result[fieldValue] = [];
        }
        result[fieldValue].push(item)
    });
    //Done!
    return result;
}

var orderdData = orderBy("Bit", mData);
```

Now for your second question:

#### How to add a color property to all the objects

In your case, where you want to add a value based on a range, you could just iterate over all objects and do the value check in a loop:

```
mData.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.Bit < 17) {
        item.color = 'yellow';
    } else if (item.Bit < 27) {
        item.color = 'blue';
    } else {
        item.color = 'red';
    }
});
//and then again ordering
var orderdData = orderBy("Bit", mData);
```

Update: [Full code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6mq1dbn/)

Comment: You have given a great answer, @Tiddo. If you do not mind, could u please combine both in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

If you know which bit # you're looking for, the `Array` prototype has a function called [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) that you can use for this purpose.

```
var twentyseven = mData.filter(function(el, i, arr) {return el.Bit === 27;});
```

However, if you want to split them all out into arrays dynamically, without needing to know the bit #s beforehand, you can use the `Array` prototype's [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function:

```
var bitArrays = {};
mData.forEach(function(el, i, arr){
    if(!bitArrays[el.Bit]){
        bitArrays[el.Bit] = [];
    } 
    bitArrays[el.Bit].push(el);
});
```

This approach will give you an object containing an array for each bit #. You could, for example, access the array of objects with a Bit of 27 by accessing `bitArrays[27]`

Here's some working example code:

```js
// helper code to log to HTML
var log = (function(output) {
  return function(input) {
    output.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", input);
  }
})(document.getElementById("output"));

var bitArrays = {};
var mData=[{A: "148.0", Bit: 27 ,Ic: "0.4",ked: "229.0",Ted: "228.9985"},
{A: "148.0", Bit: 27 ,Ic: "0.4",ked: "229.0",Ted: "2285"},
{A: "148.0", Bit: 17 ,Ic: "0.4",ked: "259.0",Ted: "28"},
{A: "148.0", Bit: 27 ,Ic: "0.4",ked: "279.0",Ted: "28"},             
{A: "148.0", Bit: 27 ,Ic: "0.4",ked: "239.0",Ted: "82"},
{A: "148.0", Bit: 17 ,Ic: "0.4",ked: "219.0",Ted: "22"},
{A: "148.0", Bit: 16 ,Ic: "0.4",ked: "239.0",Ted: "22"},      
{A: "148.0", Bit: 17 ,Ic: "0.4",ked: "259.0",Ted: "22"}];

mData.forEach(function(el, i, arr){
  if(!bitArrays[el.Bit]){
    bitArrays[el.Bit] = [];
  } 
  bitArrays[el.Bit].push(el);
});

log(JSON.stringify(bitArrays));
```

```html
<div id="output" />
```